# ¿Validar si existe carpeta y abrir su archivo PDF? C# SILVERLIGHT

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, silverlight

quiero saber la manera en la que pueda validar si existe una carpeta, y si existe, abrir los archivos que tiene dentro, en este caso son PDF'S, me explico:
Tengo una ruta de un servidor en donde tengo almacenadas varias carpetas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y dentro de esas carpetas tengo archivos PDF, en este caso solo hay un archivo pdf dentro de esta carpeta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es validar si existe la carpeta (por el nombre de la carpeta), y si existe, abrir los archivos que vienen dentro de dicha carpeta

Por el momento tengo el siguiente código:

```html
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlElement myFrame = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("_sl_historyFrame");
            if (myFrame != null)
            {
                myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("width", "1024");
                myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("height", "768");
                Uri uri = new Uri(@"\\192.458.1.478\UploadFileMobilePDF\9977524\29b3e866-e695-4c53-ba33-210f5be74885.pdf");
                string path = uri.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
                myFrame.SetAttribute("src", path);
                myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("left", "0");
                myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("top", "50");
                myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("visibility", "visible");
            }
```

Ahí lo que hago es harcodear la ruta para abrir el PDF que esta en esa carpeta, pero lo que quiero es saber la manera en que me muestre el o los archivo(s) que vienen dentro de la carpeta, siempre y cuando exista la carpeta por el nombre, hacer todo el procedimiento al presionar un botón y empiece la validación y abrir los archivos.

Espero haberme explicado, si requieren mas explicación estaré al pendiente

Comment: Momento, es una app hecha en Windows Phone 7?

Comment: No, es desarrollo nuevo,  la estoy desarrollando en visual studio 2012 y estoy usando silverlight

Comment: Creo que vas a tener que hablar seriamente con el jefe del área... "Microsoft Silverlight will reach the end of support on October 12, 2021. Silverlight development framework is currently only supported on Internet Explorer 10 and Internet Explorer 11, with support for Internet Explorer 10 ending on January 31, 2020. There is no longer support for Chrome, Firefox, or any browser using the Mac operating system." Extraído de: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4511036/silverlight-end-of-support

Comment: Si ya eso lo sabemos, ya estamos migrando a Angular, pero por el momento si puede haber manera de realizar esa tarea?

Comment: Podrías cargar los archivos mediante un visualizador online como el google viewer y le pasas la ruta, aunque no sabría decirte si funcionaría llamando archivos dentro de una intranet, es probable que funcione esta idea, como que tampoco funcione 50/50.

Comment: ¿Intentaste esto ^^^^^^?

Comment: Si, también lo intente pero me manda un mensaje de No hay una vista previa disponible.