# Recorrer los archivos PDF de una carpeta, c# usando SILVERLIGHT

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Mi principal objetivo es recorrer y abrir los archivos PDF de una carpeta especificando la ruta, y usando Silverlight, tengo el siguiente codigo para poder recorrer los archivos

```html
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlElement myFrame = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("_sl_historyFrame");
            if (myFrame != null)
            {
                myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("width", "1024");
                myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("height", "768");
                Uri uri = new Uri(@"\\192.168.1.216\UploadFileMobilePDF\" + transfer.IdTransfer);
                string path = uri.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
                //string path = new Uri(uri.ToString()).LocalPath;
                //string uriPath = @"\\192.168.1.216\UploadFileMobilePDF\" + transfer.IdTransfer;
                //string path = new Uri(uriPath).LocalPath;
                foreach (var dirFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
                {
                    myFrame.SetAttribute("src", path);
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("left", "0");
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("top", "50");
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("visibility", "visible");
                    //foreach(var pdfFiles in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirFile.ToString()))
                    //{
                    //    myFrame.SetAttribute("src", path);
                    //    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("left", "0");
                    //    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("top", "50");
                    //    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("visibility", "visible");
                    //}
                }
               
            }
```

Usando ese bucle foreach me da un error que es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso el .EnumerateFiles() ya que no me permite utilizar el metodo .GetFiles()

Cualquier ayuda sobre como recorrer los archivos de manera correcta, se los agradecería

Comment: ¿En qué se diferencia de tus otras preguntas?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290826/validar-si-existe-carpeta-y-abrir-su-archivo-pdf-c-silverlight

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291253/mostrar-documento-pdf-c-silverlight

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291402/error-operacion-de-archivo-no-permitida-acceso-a-la-ruta-denegado-c-silverlig

Comment: En el código que utilizo, que he hecho modificaciones y me arroga el error, o mejor seria editar la misma pregunta?

Comment: Busqué en Google: "si un ensamblado que implementa el objeto de seguridad personalizado hace referencia a otros ensamblados, agregue los ensamblados a los que hace referencia a la lsta de ensamblados de plena confianza"

Comment: Primer enlace: https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/771ss30w(v=vs.120)

Comment: Ahora, respondiendo al comentario que haces, basado en la interacción que has tenido en el sitio, es una sola pregunta que ha ido "evolucionando", motivo por el cual el buen @gbianchi te mencionó sobre la duplicidad de la pregunta.